# How can I get a checkbox input to be on the left side of a <div>?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="w25">
   <span>True</span>
   <input data-ng-model="answer.correct" 
          type="checkbox">
</div>
```

The div is approximately 150px wide. What happens is that the input appears in the center with about 70px on each side.

How can I get the `<input>` to go to the left ?

Comment: Can you share CSS with us? Or if possible make JSFIDDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span` and `input` elements are both inline by default, and the checbox will be placed next to the span element. I assume no further styling is applied on any of the elements. If it is, please post your css.

If you want to place the checkbox on the left, you can either:

- Turn around the span and input (input first, then the span)
- Float the input to the left (style="float: left;")
- Use explicit positioning (eg. `postition: absolute; left: 0;`)

As [illustrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/LL9LH/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input data-ng-model="answer.correct" style="float:left" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have `inherit` styles from your div `class="w25"`. But you can try with this:

- One change the order:

  ```
  <div class="w25">
    <input data-ng-model="answer.correct" type="checkbox">
    <span>True</span>
  </div>
  ```
- Two add this properties on your CSS to be sure each element has the correct properties:

  ```
  .w25 input, .w25 span {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
  ```

View this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/W7YE7/1/**

Answer (score 0):

First, change the positions of input and span (if you can do it) and see if it works:

```
<div class="w25">
  <input data-ng-model="answer.correct" type="checkbox">
  <span>True</span>
</div>
```

If it doesn't work, try to change the input for:

```
<input data-ng-model="answer.correct" style="float: left" type="checkbox">
```

If it doesn't work too, try it:

```
<div class="w25">
  <div style="width:70px; display: inline;"><span>True</span></div>
  <div style="float:left; width:70px; display: inline;"><input data-ng-model="answer.correct" type="checkbox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the CSS style `float: left;`
Usually it's a better practice to put the styling in a separate CSS file, not inline, so if you can do that, assign a class to the input, like this:

```
<div class="w25">
<span>True</span>
<input class="yourclass" data-ng-model="answer.correct" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

And in the css file:

```
.yourclass {float: left;}
```

Here you have the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A52nS/

Answer (score -1):

try this css

```
.w25{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: ya, i could have asked for css and then try to answer